# Facebook API 2.1 how to query and get the data output

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to get my id via the  Facebook API 2.1

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me&fields=id&access_token="+accesstoken

I get error 200 but no data.

Does anyone have an example how to get and extract my id, name, or any data from query 2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because of me&field=id must be me?field=id

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me?fields=id&access_token=accesstoken
```

for all public user information

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me?access_token=accesstoken
```

i would recommend you to use Facebook SDK. see [Using the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1)

Example graph api me request with facebook sdk:

```
    new Request(
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        "/me",
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                if (graphObject != null) {
                    if (graphObject.getProperty("id") != null) {
                        String fbId = graphObject.getProperty("id").toString();
                        String userName = graphObject.getProperty("name").toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();
```

Comment: error 400 means your token is expired. renew it and then simply do the json parsing staff

Comment: The error is here                                                  try {
                                                   jsonObject = new JSONObject(
                                                           response.getGraphObject()
                                                                   .getInnerJSONObject()
                                                                   .toString());

Comment: I did the json parasing in v1.0, but it is not working for me in v2.0 how do I write the json parsing?

Comment: v2.1 see documentation

Comment: /me you already have them. you dont need to specificly set field = id,name